# Sending data from an Adapter to a Fragment in Android. getArguments() returns null

Tags: android

I want to use the data in fragments which is present in the `Adapter`. I am using `setArguments()` to send the data from `Adapter`, and `getArguments()` to receive the data.

But when I debug it, I am getting a `nullpointerException` at `getArguments`.

This is how I am sending the data and receiving it.

In Adapter, to send the data.

```
ReversalFragment f1 = new ReversalFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String transId = item.getTxId();
bundle.putString("tId", transId);
f1.setArguments(bundle);
```

fragment class, to get the data.

```
Bundle arguments = getArguments();

if(arguments!=null) {

    String transId = arguments.getString("tId");

    if (transId != null ) {

        txView.setText(transId);
    }
}
```

Can Anyone help me out how to handle this exception and why is `getArguments()` null??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check if the **transId** string is not null before adding that string to the bundle. If **item.getTxId()** returned null then String transId will also be null. Apart from that I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: Bundle arguments = this.getArguments();
and if(argument.bundle.containsKey("tId")){
//do stuff
}
try with this

Comment: I hope getArguments() is not returning null instead it might be possible arguments.getString("tId"); is returning null to you.

Comment: @Kingston- transId string is not null. Checked that.

Comment: @JinalPatel- That hasn't helped too. Even though I use this.getArguments(), it returns null and doesn't go till if condition to implement it.

Comment: @Mahendra- I debugged it. getArguments() is only null. It doesn't step into the if condition.

Comment: I hope u are commiting the fragment.

Comment: @Drv-No I am not. Do I have to?

Comment: I think you are using different object for your fragment

Comment: Show your code which is adding or replacing your fragment.

Answer (score 1):

use can setTag on a view in adapter and getTag in your Fragment.
there are in built methods you can pass objects in setTag();

```
@ExportedProperty
        public Object getTag() {
            throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
        }

    public void setTag(Object tag) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call the fragment class object in your Adapter class.Suppose your fragment class name is FragmentB then you should call FragmentB class Object because in your program, it is unable to find out your fragment where do you want to pass the data.

```
 FragmentB f1 = new FragmentB();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    String transId = item.getTxId();
    bundle.putString("tId", transId);
    f1.setArguments(bundle);
```

Comment: I am using the fragment class object while passing the data in Adapter class.

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying the name of the Fragment clearly, 
instead of `Fragment f1 = new Fragment();`
write `Your_Fragment_Name f1 = new Your_Fragment_Name();`
it will work then.

Comment: @inkedTechie- Actually I am doing that but edited the name while writing this question. I will change it in the question too wait.

Comment: @Adheesh in that case it does not seem like there's any problem with the code. How are you transacting the fragment? This will not work incase you are using a static fragment. Please include code for transacting the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the other way around. In your current approach you are creating an object for the fragment class in you adapter class and assigning the values to that object, but when you are in your Fragment class it creates a new instance and the values are actually null.

So you must try something like this:

put `getArgument()` and `setArgument()` methods in your Adapter class.
I am pretty sure you create the object for Adapter in Fragment class to set it into listview or anything, at that time set and get the values.

For example

in Fragment class:

```
BaseAdapter adapter = new Adapter(); //constructor called and values set
Bundle args = adapter.getArgument();
```

now you can have the exact arguments in you need without making any further method calls

Adapter class:

```
Bundle bundle;
public Adapter(){
bundle = new Bundle();
//put required values
}

public Bundle getArgument(){
return bundle;
}
```

note that bundle variable is global in Adapter class

Answer (score 0):

Since you would be creating the adapter from your fragment means you have access to your adapter in your fragment.

You can create `public String getString()` in your adapter and after the adapter is initialized you can call this method in your fragment as `adapter.getString()`